# Can GraphEngine TSL-files import other TSL-files?

Tags: graphengine

can TSL-files import other TSL-files?
Imagine a struct that is outsourced in file "b.tsl" and
another file would like to use it.

I've looked up the official web page and parts of the web,
but didn't find something.. Is there any option available?

Kind regards

Seargent

Comment: Sometimes the obvious and common way is the right one.. `include "b.tsl";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, importing other TSL files is possible in GraphEngine, by just placing `include $PathToTheDir$\b.tsl;` at the beginning of the TSL file.

If the TSL files are in the same GraphEngine modeling project,
no explicit importing is necessary for them. Multiple TSL files are permitted, and they can be recognized by each other. My suggestion is just splitting the cell and struct definitions into different TSL files (the TSL filenames don't matter), adding a TSL file to the project is much convenient in my opinion.